# How to reload the outputText content after commandButton execution?

Tags: jsf

Here is my TestBean

```
@ManagedBean (name="testBean")  
@SessionScoped  

public class TestBean implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
    private int testParameter; 

    public int getTestParameter() {
        return testParameter;
    }
    public void setTestParameter(int testParameter) {
        this.testParameter = testParameter;
    }    
}
```

---

Here is my Text.xhtml

```
 <h:commandButton value="Click Me" action="#{testBean.setTestParameter(123456)}"/>   
             <h:outputText value="#{testBean.testParameter}" id="outputTestId"/>
```

When I click the button, the `<h:output` does not get reloaded, and still shows zero `0` (the default for `int`) . How can I reload it?

Why doesn't it get reloaded? I specified `@SessionScoped`.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Information to provide when asking JSF questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)

You are missing a h:form.

```
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="Click Me"
            action="#{testBean.setTestParameter(123456)}" />
        <h:outputText value="#{testBean.testParameter}" id="outputTestId" />
    </h:form>
```

Comment: I have had form I didn't put it I've the question sorry

Comment: Please provide the complete xhtml file and details of you JSF implementation jar.  The xhtml attached is working on JSF 2.2 mojarra with Tomcat 7.